# iptables REDIRECT and only allow dport

Tags: iptables

Quick iptables question, I hope.

We're running this in iptables:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 57875 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5060
```

and then we also have:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 57875 -j ACCEPT
```

And what we want is to only allow access to port 5060 by a 57875 redirect, and NOT directly by 5060, but the two lines above aren't accomplishing that.

How can we accomplish this?

[root@dev1 ~]# iptables -L -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-FTP  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 21
fail2ban-apache-auth  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80
fail2ban-SIP  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
fail2ban-SIP  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
fail2ban-BadBots  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22
fail2ban-recidive  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:57875
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:57875
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.90.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.87.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.187.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.77.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  199.91.70.160/27     0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  108.23.78.98         0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  100.9.107.47         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  100.9.107.47         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  67.212.84.21         0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     udp  --  50.22.102.242        0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     udp  --  50.22.101.14         0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     udp  --  72.9.149.25          0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     udp  --  176.9.39.206         0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:10000:20000

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-BadBots (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-FTP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-SIP (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-apache-auth (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-recidive (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

[root@dev1 ~]# iptables -t nat -L

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:57875 redir ports 5060

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: probably with NAT and redirecting to `127.0.0.1:5060` and only accepting on `-d 127.0.0.1 --dport 5060`  but It kind of sounds like you are trying to solve a separate problem with this weird setup.

Comment: This is true. We're trying to us an other than 5060 TCP bind port for SIP (yes, using TCP for the SIP signaling), but our Cisco ASA seems to mangle the packets, causing one way audio. This is only a problem when using a port other than 5060, using 'tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0:7775'.  So we've had to assign our asterisk box a public IP and use iptables to tighten things down. Well, we also want to do the same for UDP (long story), but we need the bind port to stay 5060 for UDP, hence this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use nat in first rule.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 57875 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5060
```

If you have problems again run this command and post information from them

```
iptables -L -n
iptables -t nat -L
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Info posted in original question.